# python:ImportError: cannot import name 'plot'

Tags: python

I have a problem where I want to use highcharts.
My python version is 3.4.

When I run "import charts", I get the error below.

---

```
ImportError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a030638da752> in <module>()
      1 import pymongo
----> 2 import charts

/Users/Alex/anaconda2/envs/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/charts/__init__.py in <module>()
      3 __version__ = '0.4.6'
      4 
----> 5 from plot import plot, plotasync, line, area, spline, pie
      6 from server import run_server
      7 

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot'
```

Is there anyone who can show me the correct way?

Thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug charts package 'No module named 'plot' ' Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559475/how-to-debug-charts-package-no-module-named-plot-error)

Comment: yes it's same. But i still don't know how to deal with it. and i can import charts in python 2.7, but in python 3.x it doesn't work.

Comment: add the path to the `charts` package to your `pythonpath` environment variable, since you can import charts in python2.7, add it's path to python3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath

Comment: it's already in my pythonpath, but i still cannot import charts. feelsbadman

Comment: you're right, I got the same error, it looks like maybe it's an open bug https://github.com/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts/issues/49

Comment: alright. I should do my work in python 2. Thank you so much!